# Error: 'clientAccessToken' cannot be empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, dialogflow-es, api-ai

I'm new to learning javascript and I'm running into an issue with trying to deploy this web app using heroku: https://github.com/girliemac/web-speech-ai. The error message says:

> Error: 'clientAccessToken' cannot be empty.

I am getting this error message after I have already written the api key in the `.env` and `app.json` file. Can someone help me resolve this?

Edit: I already have the dotenv module installed.

Comment: https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client/issues/104

Comment: @MartinZeitler this is an old thread without a solution that resolves the issue. bimalkumarh only comments out the code which throws the error, but doesn't solve the issue of clientAccessToken registering as empty.

Comment: Why not just provide the token, instead of complaining that there is nothing to copy & paste?

Comment: @MartinZeitler If I am understanding you correctly, you want me to provide you the api key? If so, I can not do that for security reasons.

Comment: Otherwise, I have already provided the api key in the .env and app.json files, as mentioned in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Following the documention:https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars, I was able to resolve the issue by setting the config vars. I thought just writing it in the .env of the app's root directory would work, but I also needed to write it for the heroku app as well.